# How do the audio controls work on "The Daily"?

Tags: ipad, applications, ios, audio, ui

*The Daily*, Rupert Murdoch's new iPad-only app, has a narration feature where a professional actor reads the stories.

I can't for the life of me figure out how it works. There is a headphones icon that starts it, and then you get a fast-forward arrow and a stop square. But the fast forward arrow just seems to activate the carousel, not jump to the next story. And the story you get when you press play seems random.

And I think there's only narration for some of the stories, but I'm not sure, since I can't find a controlled way to navigate.

Can anyone help to explain how this feature works in detail, so I'll stop feeling like my mom and cursing at the "broken machine"?

Answer (score 1):

The part starting at about 3:30 of [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TioAP7u1jjc#t=3m31s) might help.

Answer (score 0):

How do I deactivate auto audio @ startup? Currently when I open the app on iPad it disables any other audio I am listening to and cannot read the Daily while listening to radio or music.